# Capture the id of one or more cells of a DataGridView for Mass SMS

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, sms

I added a CheckBox to the DataGridView to be able to select several items and thus pass them to an Array to be able to send messages in bulk.

**Problem 1:** pressing on the CheckBox is not checked. It is worth mentioning that all I did was add it from the DataGridView editing properties.

**Problem 2:** to send messages in bulk use the following block in string:

```
string bloque = "";
bloque = bloque + "ID1\t112223333\tMessage\n";
```

But, I need to send those messages automatically. This means that, with the exception of the message or text, the **ID** and the **PHONE** must be loaded and / or assigned by selecting one or more **CheckBoxes** from the **DataGridView**. For this, create the following class:

```
class Example
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string cellphone{ get; set; }
        public string text{ get; set; }

        public Example() { }
        public Example(int id, string cel, string text) {
            this.id = id;
            this.cellphone= cel;
            this.text= text;
        }

        public string toString() {
            return "ID"+id+"\t" + cellphone+ "\t" + text + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this is currently the interface code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form{
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
            dtgId.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
            allId();
            dtgId.ReadOnly = true;
        }

        public void allId(){//method to populate the DataGridView
            try{
                string chain = "chain";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cadena)){
                    con.Open();
                    string query = "SELECT id FROM clients GROUP BY id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    dtgId.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){//Code to send SMS in bulk
            string user= "user";
            string pass= "pass";
            string respuesta = "";
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text);
            string cellp= txtNumber.Text;
            string text= txtText.Text;
            List<Example> item = new List<Example>();
            Example example= new Example(id, cellp, text);
            item.Add(example);
            string bloque = "";
            //bloque = bloque + "ID1\t1144444444\tMi texto 1\n";
            for (int i = 0; i > item.Count; i++){
                bloque += item[i].toString();
            }

            Uri uri = new Uri("uri");

            HttpWebRequest requestFile = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            requestFile.Method = "POST";
            requestFile.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.Append("api=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("1") + "&");
            postData.Append("usuario=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(user) + "&");
            postData.Append("clave=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(pass) + "&");
            postData.Append("separadorcampos=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tab") + "&");
            postData.Append("bloque=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(bloque) + "&");

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(postData.ToString());

            requestFile.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream requestStream = requestFile.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse webResp = requestFile.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            if (requestFile.HaveResponse){
                if (webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || webResp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted){
                    StreamReader respReader = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
                    respuesta = respReader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
                }
            }
        }

        private void dtgId_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
//With this method, pressing on a checkbox shows the id and the phone in a TextBox
            var row = dtgId.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            var id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["id"].Value.ToString());
            try{
                string conn = "cadena";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn)){
                    con.Open();
                    string sql = "SELECT id,cellphone FROM clients WHERE id=@id";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read()){
                        txtId.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                        txtNumero.Text = reader["cellphone"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }catch (SqlException exc){
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize the idea: It does not send the messages, that is, they have not reached me. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: And you're certain that the SMS sending code works?

Comment: Yeah, if i use the `bloque = bloque + "ID1\t112223333\tMessage\n";` to send sms it work @CaiusJard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I'd have done it more like this; cut down on a lot of low level/redundant code by using HttpClient to send the request, by loading the cellphone into the grid as well as the ID so we don't have to trip to the database again:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{


    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dtgId.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllId();
    }

    public void AllId()
    {//method to populate the DataGridView
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id, cellphone FROM clients GROUP BY id", "constr"))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                dt.Columns.Add("Choose", typeof(bool)); //will become a checkbox column in the grid
                dtgId.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private async void SendSms(string id, string number, string message)
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "api", "1" },
            { "usario", "user" },
            { "clave", "pass" },
            { "separadorcampos", "tab" },
            { "bloque",  $"{id}\t{number}\t{message}\n" }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("uri", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        //do whatever with response...
    }

    private void GoButton_Click(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = dtgId.DataSource as DataTable;

        foreach (DataRow ro in dt.Rows) //iterate the table
        {
            if (ro.Field<bool>("Choose")) //if ticked by user
                SendSms(ro.Field<string>("ID"), ro.Field<string>("Cellphone"), "hello, this is my message"); //send the sms
        }

    }
}
```